# Exclude a shape from opacity widget flutter

Tags: flutter

How can I add an `opacity widget` in flutter and exclude a shape like a circle or a rectangle from it? (Something like image cropper overlay.)

Comment: Might be easier to just put 2 same widgets in stack on top of each other, add an opacity to the bottom one and crop the top one to desired shape using a clipper.

Comment: @Thepeanut thanks, it was a great hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Thepeanut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9039032/thepeanut), I found an answer.

```dart
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(widget.title),
          ),
          body: Center(),
        ),
        ClipPath(
          child: Opacity(
            opacity: 0.5,
            child: Container(color: Colors.red),
          ),
          clipper: CustomClipPath(),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

class CustomClipPath extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  var radius = 96.0;

  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path path = Path();

    path.lineTo(0.0, size.height);

    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);

    path.lineTo(size.width, radius);

    path.arcToPoint(
      Offset(size.width - radius, 0.0),
      clockwise: true,
      radius: Radius.circular(radius),
    );

    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => true;
}
```